# My USB flash drive became completely bricked

Tags: partitioning, usb

I turned my 16 GB USB stick into LiveUSB for Kali with `dd`. After I was done, I wanted to format it into NTFS for watching movies, however something went bad and it is broken now. It just says ISOIMAGE as name. It can't be mounted and when I try to format it again I get the warning:

[image]

What am I supposed to do. Can it be rescued?

Edit: I have created the Liveboot and tried to format the USB both within Ubuntu. The problem is related to ubuntu and I don't agree that it is off-topic.

Comment: You need to replace the flash drive.

Comment: @Pilot6 Can you explain please? Like, is it trash now?

Comment: flash drivers are not very reliable, if used this way. It probably is dead.

Comment: May I ask a (for some people) rude question: How much did your flash drive cost?

Comment: @tim687 can't really recall

Comment: @SarpSTA Haha, if you try to open the USB drive with Windows, does it do something? Try testdisk to check if you can see the device and the partitions: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: @tim687 I tried. It was showing 0 bytes total and constantly tending to unmount.

Comment: @SarpSTA I think that you really need to replace your USB drive at this point :-P. It it completely dead

Comment: @tim687 But, it is working like a charm now?

Comment: @SarpSTA Nope, what you could do is connect it to Windows, and remove all of the partitions in the disk manager and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @tim687 I don't really understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: @SarpSTA Open the diskmanager in Windows with your USB drive connected to your Windows machine (Disk manager http://www.partition-tool.com/images/resource/win7-extend3-b.gif) Then remove all of the available partitions currently on the USB Drive and create a new one. Make sure you DISABLE quick formatting. If this doesn't work, try removing the partitions with DISKPART (http://commandwindows.com/diskpart.htm)

Comment: @tim687 Why? I already fixed it.

Comment: @SarpSTA Sorry, I didn't notice that :-P

Comment: @tim687 It is okay. I just got confused is all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been able to solve the problem.

I have tried to format it on Windows too but the problem persisted. Same thing with `gparted` and Disks too.

So I did the following:

```
sudo -i
fdisk /dev/sdx (in my case was sda)
n
-set attributes as default-
w
```

After that, went to gparted and reformatted as ntfs. And bingo!

Comment: Be very, very, **very** careful to use the correct device here. Might be better to use one of the /dev/disk/by-id/\* symlinks instead of /dev/sdx directly; much less risk of getting it wrong without noticing.

Comment: Any explanation about what this actually does?

Comment: n = new partition; w = write partition table and exit

Comment: Well, at least `/dev/sdx` doesn't point to any drive, so if a careless user just copy and paste they won't mess up their system.